# При воспроизведение мелодии ошибка error (-38, 0)

Tags: java, android, mediaplayer

Всем привет!Поиском пользовался,но не нашел решения.
Вообщем:
Естm массив мелодий,такого плана:

```
mediaPlayers[0] = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.a);
```

Всего 7 эл.массива.
И есть 7 imageview,которые так же в массиве

```
arr_imageB[0] = (ImageView) rootViewB.findViewById(R.id.b1);
```

и вот какая проблема:
нажимаю на imageview[i] все воспроизводиться,Все мелодии играют,но когда я выбираю предыдущую imageview , в логкат  такое сообщение: start called in state 1
 E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)

Вызываю данный метод для остановки предыдущей мелодии:

```
private void stopPlayerIfNeeded() {
    for (int i = 0; i < mediaPlayers.length; i++) {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayers[i];

                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {

                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.reset();

            }
        }

    }
```

Пример вызова:

```
    case R.id.b7:
  arr_imageB[6].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(View v) {

 Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(),R.anim.clickbutton);
                                                arr_imageB[6].startAnimation(anim);
  stopPlayerIfNeeded();
 mediaPlayers[6].start();
```

Так же висит предупреждение:
Should have subtitle controller already set

Answer (score 1):

по хорошему вам нужно использовать один медиаплеер, при нажатие на imageView менять dataSource. Ошибка происходит из-за того, что вы начали проигрывание, до того как плеер готов это проиграть

```
mp.setDataSource(url); 
mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
mp.prepareAsync();

public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
    player.start();
}
```

попробуйте использовать один медиаплеер, у вас упростится логика

```
 private void stopPlayerIfNeeded() {
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
}
```

при нажатии на imageView вызывайте

```
if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
   } else {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, uri);// новый трэк
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync(); //после того как плеер будет готов к проигрыванию, сработает коллбэк onPrepared(), описанный выше, и трэк начнет играть
   }
```

Comment: Спасибо!Подскажите пожалуйста, как это реализовать в моем классе:
http://pastebin.com/iFJUjaf0

Comment: Я зарефакторил немного http://pastebin.com/q47LmWmd. Но оставил todo, у тебя там один копипаст, по хорошему, твой фрагмент можно в максимум 200 строк уместить вместо 600, если избавиться от копипаста

Comment: копипаст убирать буду,думаю что циклами или методами,А потом вызывать.
или как лучше сделать,подскажите пожалуйста?
знаю,что если что-то используется в коде больше 2-х раз то нужно писать метод 
Спасибо

Comment: Извините,хотел уточнить:
 linLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DD000000"));
можно ли при воспр. мелодии изменить фон на цвет